# Wix Toolset - CustomAction - ExeCommand - 1 fails 1 succeeds. Can you help understand why?

Tags: wix

I need to run a cmd command during install, so I created a CustomAction which is set to run after InstallFiles.
The command is: Update.exe --someargs
The installer keeps on failing with:
"CustomAction RUN_UPDATE returned actual error code -1"  which means nothing to me nor google.

For the sake of experiment, I created another CustomAction which just runs a batch file, and it works.

Here are the 2 CustomActions:

```
<CustomAction Id="RUN_UPDATE" Directory="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="yes" ExeCommand="cmd.exe /c &quot;Update.exe&quot;" Return="check" />       
<CustomAction Id="RUN_BAT" Directory="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="yes" ExeCommand="cmd.exe /c &quot;runme.bat&quot;" Return="check" />
```

I really don't understand why the first one fails while the second one succeeds.
Both Update.exe and runme.bat exist in the APPLICATIONFOLDER
I use Impersonate  = yes cause my app is installed in LocalAppDir and doesn't need elevated permissions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "Update.exe" application you execute returns -1 on exit. This is considered as error reported by your action, therefore the installer fails the installation. You told the installer to do so by setting `Return="check"`. If the exe returned 0, that would be considered success (your batch file does that). You can ignore the application exit code, using `Return="ignore"`. Or make Update.exe return 0, not -1.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I run the same command (update.exe) at the cmd and then do 'echo %ErrorLevel%', the return code is 0. So I don't know why msiexec considers this as return code -1 and this is my main issue.  
I know I can ignore the return code but it feels wrong...

Comment: Do you execute "update.exe" with the same arguments and under the same account installer executes it? It may return different value depending on that.

Comment: I think I do. I just run it via CMD (same args, tried with no args also both at CMD and MSI), and I run the MSI in the same session... even using Impersonate = yes.
I'm really lost as to why this returns -1